# How do I write a shell script that takes a data file name as an argument to run my perl script?

Tags: bash, shell, perl

I am learning Perl and Shell scripting and of the challenges I was given is to write a shell script that takes a csv file as an argument and then have that shell script run my perl script (test.pl).  I can't seem to get the proper syntax down and I have terminate every time because it hangs up my terminal.

For example shell script is **test.sh**

```
#/bin/bash
./test.pl $i`
```

on my terminal I write type out

```
test.sh testfile.csv
```

Ultimately I want the test file to be read by my perl script so it can run.

Comment: have you tried with `perl test.pl $1` ?

Comment: @fra thank you! switching out $i for $1 helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error comes from the `` $i` `` part.

First the trailing backquote is probably a typo and should raise a syntax error. Second, the `i` variable is not defined, so `$i` resolve to an empty string. As it is not quoted, shell will omit it and call `test.pl` without any arguments... Thus your terminal is probably hanging because your perl script is waiting for input.

As @fra suggested, you should use `$1` instead of `$i`, hence passing the first argument passed to your bash script, to your perl script.

Depending on your perl script (shebang, execution write) you may or may not call the perl executable manually.

Comment: You and @fra were correct.  The trailing backquote was a typo that I didn't realize was there and changing out the positional parameter from --$i to --%1 helped make my script run.